Problem error 419 on my login and logout of my laravel app (edit : every form that I create is getting a 419 error)
I have error 419 when I try to log in with my app login. I have error 419 when I try to login with my app login, users have roles. Login does not need password. Here is my form:
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('loginEmploye') }}" class="px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4">
                <h1 class="font-bold text-2xl mb-5">Connexion</h1>
                @csrf

                <label for="courriel" class="text-grey text-sm font-bold mb-3">Courriel</label>
                <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full mt-2 py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline border-solid border-2 border-blue-100 px-2 py-2 rounded-lg shadow-lg shadow-blue-100 bg-white focus:ring-blue-100" name="courriel" id="courriel" type="email" placeholder="exemple@email.com">
                @error('courriel')
                    <div class="mb-5 mt-2 text-red-500">{{ $message }}</div>
                @enderror

                <button type="submit" class="shadow bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-400 focus:shadow-outline focus:outline-none text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded my-4">
                    Se connecter 
                </button>
         

here is the controller for the login :
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $employes = Employe::all();
        $user = Employe::where('courriel', $request->courriel)->first();
        $categoriesLicences = CategoriesLicence::all();
        $licences = Licence::all();
        $fournisseurs = Fournisseur::all();
        $demandes = Demande::all();
        $infosRbq = InfosRbq::all();
    
        if (session()->has('user')) {
            logger('User session exists: ' . session('user'));
        } else {
            logger('No user session found.');
        }
    
        if ($user) {
            Auth::login($user);
            logger('Utilisateur connecté : ' . $user->role);
            
            session(['user' => $user->courriel]);
    
            if ($user->role == "Administrateur") {
                return view('GestionRole.role', compact('employes'));
            } elseif ($user->role == "Responsable" || $user->role == "Commis") {
                return view('listeFournisseurs', compact('employes', 'categoriesLicences', 'licences', 'fournisseurs', 'demandes', 'infosRbq'));
            }
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('loginEmploye')->withErrors(["Information invalide"]);
        }
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return View('GestionRole.login');
    }

and here my route
//Route pour le login d'employe
Route::get('/loginEmploye', 
[EmployeController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('loginEmploye');

Route::post('/loginEmploye', 
[EmployeController::class, 'login'])->name('loginPost');

I tried to modify the routes, the middlewares and my controller but nothing solved the problem

I think the route you use in the form action is not the good one. You use the name of the GET route, not the POST one.
